# Function preg_replace

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I have a function in wordpress

```
<?php $string = get_the_content();?>
<?php $string = preg_replace('/(<blockquote)(.*)(<\/blockquote>)/', "", $string); ?>
<?php echo $string;?>
```

it's remove blockquote tag but also remove `<p> </p>`
anybody know how to do not remove `<p>`

Comment: Could you provide us with an example of your HTML?

Comment: Please add the value of `$string` you are using to the question. There is an `edit` link below your question. _Use it._

Comment: Actually, the code above does not remove just the `<blockquote>` tag but also everything that is enclosed by  `<blockquote>` and `</blockquote>`. So if there happens to be a `<p>` inside of the blockquote tags, than that gets removed, too.

Comment: $string is like

<blockquote><p>text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 </p></blockquote>
<p>text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 </p>
<p>text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 </p>

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
$content = preg_replace('/<blockquote>(.*?)<\/blockquote>/', '', get_the_content());
```

Comment: Why would OP try this? What does it do? How is it different? (it appears to be the exact same code, just reorganized)?

Comment: i don't know why but when i using your code in wordpress the <p> paragraps are not in the <html> code, anyway thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

i do something like this

```
<?php $the_content = get_the_content();?>
<?php $bad_tags    = ['/(<blockquote)(.*)(<\/blockquote>)/'];?>
<?php $strip_tags  = preg_replace( $bad_tags, "" , $the_content );?>
<?php echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $strip_tags );?>
```

it's remove blockquote and text inide but leave all the rest oft text and styling